# How to configure a proxy in a new network location using Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, bash, proxy

I'm writing a bash script, which will create new network location and configure it. The question is - how to add proxy settings to specific network location using terminal or bash script?

P.S. I'm creating new location using `networksetup -createlocation <location name>`

Answer (score 1):

Found this [`networksetup` manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html). To do this, you just need to write

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Service name (e.g. Wi-Fi)" proxy.server.com port
```